# how to make custom link in wordpress

Tags: wp-list-table

Hello guys I have a question to make a link below user list.
Please check myspace edit link from  picture.[image]
the below code used for this link:

```
function cgc_ub_action_links($actions, $user_object) {
        $actions\['edit_badges'\] = "<a class='cgc_ub_edit_badges' href='site_url?page_id=13&um_user=$user_id&profiletab=main&um_action=edit" . admin_url( "users.php?page=cgc-badges&action=cgc_edit_badges&amp;user=$user_object->ID") . "'>" . __( 'Edit MySpace', 'cgc_ub' ) . "</a>";
        return $actions;
    }
    add_filter('user_row_actions', 'cgc_ub_action_links', 10, 2);
```

please check "href=" i want to make a link here when admin click this link he will be transfer to a new link like https://localhost/sitename/page_id=13&um_user=$12&profiletab=main&um_action=edit

How can i do that please help me.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming the `\` are not part of your code, but if they are then those need to be removed. You also are trying to use `$user_id` without ever declaring it.

Here is how I would write the function:

```
function cgc_ub_action_links( $actions, $user_object ) {

    $url = add_query_arg( array(
        'page_id'    => 13,
        'um_user'    => $user_object->ID,
        'profiletab' => 'main',
        'um_action'  => 'edit',
    ), site_url() );

    $actions['edit_badges'] = "<a class='cgc_ub_edit_badges' href='" . esc_url( $url ) . "'>" . __( 'Edit MySpace', 'cgc_ub' ) . "</a>";

    return $actions;
}
add_filter( 'user_row_actions', 'cgc_ub_action_links', 10, 2 );
```

I have fixed the misuse of using `$user_id` and replaced it with the passed in user ID by using `$user_object->ID`. Since you are trying to link to a front-end page and not an admin page then it makes more sense to just add the query args to the main site URL.

I hope this helps!